# How can I put lineWidth attribute of the text in canvas in pixels?

Tags: html, canvas

How can I put lineWidth of the text in canvas in pixels.

Whenever I put ctx.lineWidth = 3px; the whole text goes blank. Only when ctx.lineWidth = 3; it works in the script. And when its 3 does it means 3 pixels or some other unit?

```
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
  <script>

    var c = document.querySelector("#c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.font = "bold 36pt impact";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3; // here is the problem. I want to use pixels
    //ctx.lineWidth = 3px; // it goes blank if I use this
    ctx.strokeText("Hello Hello!", 50, 50);

    //image.src = "http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/underwire/2010/06/fry_660.jpg";
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, `context.lineWidth` takes pixel values -- no need to specify `px`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this always come down to scale issues.  You are trying to to match the pixel value from the CSS to the pixel value of the canvas.

The problem comes in when the canvas width and height is set to a different value then the clientWidth/clientHeight.

```js
    var c = document.querySelector("#c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    
    var textSize = 36
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.font = "bold " + textSize + "px impact";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3; // here is the problem. I want to use pixels
    //ctx.lineWidth = 3px; // it goes blank if I use this
    ctx.strokeText("Hello Hello! (36px)", 50, 50);

    var scale = c.clientWidth / c.width;
     ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fill();
   ctx.font = "bold " + textSize / scale + "px impact";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3; // here is the problem. I want to use pixels
    //ctx.lineWidth = 3px; // it goes blank if I use this
    ctx.strokeText("Hello Hello! (36px * scale)", 50, 200);

    //image.src = "http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/underwire/2010/06/fry_660.jpg";
```

```html
<body style="width: 400px">
  <div style="font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; font-family: impact">Hello Hello  (css)</div>
  <canvas id="c" style="width: 100%" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
```

When you adjust for scale go to the correct size